# Complexity of searching in a list and in a dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

Let's say I have a class:

```
class C
{
    public int uniqueField;
    public int otherField;
}
```

This is very simplified version of the actual problem. I want to store multiple instances of this class, where "uniqueField" should be unique for each instance.

What is better in this case?

a) Dictionary with uniqueField as the key

```
Dictionary<int, C> d;
```

or b) List?

```
List<C> l;
```

In the first case (a) the same data would be stored twice (as the key and as the field of a class instance). But the question is: Is it faster to find an element in dictionary than in list? Or is the equally fast?

a)

```
d[searchedUniqueField]
```

b)

```
l.Find(x=>x.uniqueField==searchedUniqueField);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you've got quite a lot of instances, it's likely to be *much* faster to find the item in the dictionary. Basically a `Dictionary<,>` is a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), with O(1) lookup other than due to collisions.

Now if the collection is really small, then the extra overhead of finding the hash code, computing the right bucket and then looking through that bucket for matching hash codes, then performing a key equality check can take longer than just checking each element in a list.

If you *might* have a lot of instances but *might* not, I'd usually pick the dictionary approach. For one thing it expresses what you're actually trying to achieve: a simple way of accessing an element by a key. The overhead for small collections is unlikely to be very significant unless you have far more small collections than large ones.

Comment: I'd agree and just add that there is also a cost to fill up a dictionary vs a list.
If your sole interest is in researching an item, then go for that answer, if you also care about speed when filling up your collection, then further thinking might be needed (in regard of the size of the collection).
i.e filling a dictionary needs checking for duplicata, while filling a list does not.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dictionary when the number of lookups greatly exceeds the number of insertions. It is fine to use List when you will always have fewer than four items.

Reference - http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-time

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that your client will not create a duplication of the key, you may want your class to be responsible to create the unique key. Therefore once the unique key generation is the responsibility of the class , dictionary or list is the client decision.